# Should I initialize dates in the reducer or in an action?

Tags: reactjs, date, react-native, redux

Simple question here, one of my reducers holds a Date piece of state. My question is:

1. when defining the reducer's initial state, should I pass a Date() object or an empty String/Object to the reducer and then initialize it with an actuall Date() result with an action?
2. And in the case of being the current date?

Comment: Well you wouldn't want an actual date stored if it's not the correct date, right? leave it null until you're ready...

Comment: Yeah, I think is anti-pattern because of immutability, logical thing would be to keep it as you say but I was asked this question couple of days ago and wanted to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: and what about if it is the current date?

Comment: As @caesay said if you want to populate it later in your application, leave it null and populate when it's the right time. If you want to get the date at the moment of your initialization or you really have to initialize it with a fixed date, you can store a `Date()` object. It really depends on what your application need.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know what the best practices are.

Comment: The best practice is to do whatever makes the most sense for your specific case. Questions like this can't be answered, because every single use case could have a conflicting answer.